# Manipulating scrollbars in third-party application

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I need to create an application which do the following:

At the beginning we have notepad window open with a lot of text in it.

Our application must scroll through this file and take notepad window screenshot after each scroll action.

I've tried to achieve this using SBM_GETRANGE, SBM_GETRANGE, SBM_SETPOS but it does not work for me.

Please note that emulating keyboard events (e.g. PageDown, PageUp) is not an option for me because this application should also work with other applications which may not support keyboard shortcuts for manipulating scrolls.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your "other application" include applications that draws scrollbars themselves like IE, Windows Live Messenger or WPF/DirectX apps?

Comment: I don't know offhand, but if you have access to a laptop, you might to see what messages the Synaptics touchpad driver sends if you drag along the edge of the touchpad (or similarly for middle-click scrolling for trackpoints on Thinkpads).  Or maybe take a look at SnagIt! which does what you want already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to manipulate the scrollbar directly - instead SetFocus() to the text window, then send Page Down messages. If there are applications where you *must* manipulate the scrollbar, you should get its window handle and send the messages there.

Comment: As I have already said - emulating keyboard events is not a option. Or you mean some other "Page Down message"?
I already have notepad window handle same as edit control handle and still can't manipulate scrollbars by sending scrollbar messages to them.

Comment: 1. I should have remembered: Notepad is NOT a 'normal' windows application. The "scrollbar", for example, is not a normal scrollbar (it doesn't show up in Spy++).

Comment: 2. As I said, if the target application only accepts input to the scrollbar itself, send keystroke messages to the scrollbar.

Comment: In all applications I've already analyzed scrollbar is not a separate control (if that's what you mean).